# Would it be appropriate to draw attention to Ask Patents software prior art requests on MSO?

Tags: discussion, meta

Recently [this question was posted on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293153). Main points:

- Occasionally a prior art request for a software patent pops up on [Ask Patents](http://askpatents.com).
- The folks on Ask Patents aren't always knowledgeable about software, and so expert input would be useful for prior art (where prior art isn't necessarily another patent, but rather e.g. commonly used algorithms that a programmer would be familiar with, etc.).
- Ask Patents is not very active, and these questions are apparently very rare (reportedly only one so far this year).

Being strongly in support of Ask Patents' philosophy, myself, I'm trying to think of ways to support them (so far, my only suggestion on that post wasn't exactly the greatest idea).

My question is: If and when one of these software prior art requests come up, would it be acceptable to make a post here on MSO to draw attention to the Ask Patents post somehow? And, if so, how could such a request be presented so as not to appear too "spammy"?

So far the best suggestion over there is to ask around in chat, which is a fine idea, although only a relatively small number of users are active in chat. I'm trying to think of some other options to pull expertise in on those types of questions.

[Here is an example](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/16307/prior-art-for-us20150095841-a1-composable-analytics-and-data-flow-based-progra) of a software-based prior art request that could benefit from the input of somebody familiar with graphical programming environments and existing applications and techniques.

Comment: @PaulCrovella Good idea with social media. For the latter concern, that could *probably* be addressed by linking back to this post (in the case where it's agreed to do this) as a reminder.

Comment: Maybe we could run featured (or otherwise specially-tagged) prior art requests in the SO community ad slot some of the time.  (Mind you, we haven't even had a 2017 community ad post yet, and SO devs can't do anything until they hire a manager, so...)

Comment: Getting these requests exposed to the communities that can help with them seems like a good goal, but MSO doesn't seem like the right forum; ideally we could have a Featured Prior Art Request in the Stack Overflow and Software Engineering sidebars. That would require dev time, though.

Comment: I've added an example courtesy of [Eric Shain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293153/directing-prior-art-searches-from-ask-patents#comment952704_293153).

Answer (score 3):

No, a search for prior art on a topic isn't a suitable question on MSO.  MSO is for questions about SO as a site, not for featuring questions from other sites.

Comment: Does it make any difference to you if the post is "Is there prior art for [this patent]?" vs "[This] was just posted on Ask Patents and could use some input?". That is: I definitely don't think the prior art request *itself* would be appropriate on MSO. What's up in the air is: a call to view the Ask Patents post, with the MSO post involving no actual details or discussion of the request itself. (I just want to be clear on that, not sure if it was clear in my original post.) Also noting that: At least if current AP patterns keep up, there's maybe 2-3 per year I'd imagine.

Comment: @JasonC Is, "[This] was just posted on Ask Patents and could use some input? a question that is asking about SO as a site?  Because that's what MSO is here for.

Comment: [1/2] I'm having trouble formulating a response to that because I can't decide if I want to match your level of pedanticism or not but I will say this: It's rare but not unheard of to have discussions/announcements here that don't relate to specific, concrete SO topics. It's also not unheard of in *other* SE communities to make occasional meta topic exceptions based on evaluation of the general good that something might do, after appropriate discussion on meta of course.  ...

Comment: [2/2] ... I am not claiming that that's a rationale, and [M]SO is not other communities. All I am saying is, in this world, sometimes there's a bigger picture, and sometimes we do things in the name of being *good*. Fwiw I officially neither support nor oppose your (or anybody else's) opinion of "no" here, and am refraining from arguing for or against it -- this is just a bit of brainstorming.